# Filter binding source by like syntax with integer value

Tags: c#, sql, binding, listbox

I want to filter listbox that fill with data by using binding source.

The field in the table is an integer and there is the code:

```
tbCarBindingSource.Filter = "Car_ID LIKE '" + Txt_Car_ID_ForAll.Text + "%'";
```

and when I try to run the program, it gives me these errors :
[image: Screen]

Comment: You can't use `like` with integers (that is what the error is saying). Integers are in SQL compared (for equality) by `=`. The `%` also doesn't make much sense with integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change to

```
tbCarBindingSource.Filter =  string.Format("convert(Car_ID, 'System.String') Like '%{0}%' ",Txt_Car_ID_ForAll.Text);
```